# NHibernate Exception: VendorHeadAccount is not mapped

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I'm learning NHibernate.
I'm trying to insert the `VendorHeadaccount` in database table `VendorHeadAccount`.
On insertion it throw the exception:

> VendorHeadaccount is not mapped

Here is the code which throw the exception:

```
void Create(VendorHeadaccount entity)
{
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    IQuery q = session .CreateQuery("insert into VendorHeadaccount (AccountName, Createddate, Createdby) select entity.AccountName, entity.CreatedDate, entity.CreatedBy from OtherObject entity ");
    q.ExecuteUpdate();
    session.getTransaction().commit();               
}
```

Here is My VendorHeadaccount class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Avanza.Atms.Database.Domains
{
    public class VendorHeadaccount
    {
        private int _headAccountId;
        private string _accountName;
        private string _createdBy;
        private DateTime? _createdDate;

        public VendorHeadaccount() { }
        public virtual int HeadAccountId
        {
            get
            {
                return this._headAccountId;
            }
            set
            {
                this._headAccountId = value;
            }
        }

        public virtual string AccountName
        {
            get
            {
                return this._accountName;
            }
            set
            {
                this._accountName = value;
            }
        }

        public virtual string Createdby
        {
            get
            {
                return this._createdBy;
            }
            set
            {
                this._createdBy = value;
            }
        }

        public virtual DateTime? Createddate
        {
            get
            {
                return this._createdDate;
            }
            set
            {
                this._createdDate = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the Hibernate mapping:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hibernate-mapping assembly="Atms.Database" namespace="Atms.Database.Domains" xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
    <class name="VendorHeadaccount" table="VendorHeadAccount" lazy="true" >
        <id name="HeadAccountId" column="HeadAccountId">
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <property name="AccountName">
            <column name="HeadAccountName" sql-type="int" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="Createddate">
            <column name="CreatedDate" sql-type="datetime" not-null="false" />
        </property>
        <property name="Createdby">
            <column name="CreatedBy" sql-type="nvarchar" not-null="false" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Don't know how to resolve this. Any Idea why I get this error?

Answer (score 0):

How are you building the Configuration instance? The mapping should be in the same folder as the class, have the same name and the .hbm.xml extension, be marked as embedded resource in the Visual Studio project, and you should add that assembly to the Configuration instance.

Comment: The mapping was not marked as embedded resource. Know insertion is working. Thank you.